# Negative Lookahead work around for RE2 Syntax

Tags: regex, email, google-app-engine, go, re2

I was hoping to figure out how make re2 syntax work with a regular expression like the following:

```
(?!(support|help|admin|contact))@example\.com
```

Where you do not match on *exactly* those terms above.

For example, it should match:

```
test@example.com
hello@example.com
```

but not match:

```
support@example.com
help@example.com
```

i I cannot figure out a way for exactly those terms. I have seen a lot of work arounds where it requires you to test if it does match in golang/the re2 processer, and then return false. However this is not possible, because a service requires the regex, and I cannot ask it to alternate the match value.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would consider an API using only a regex where one might want to exclude matches to be broken. Unfortunately there's not much you can do here.

Comment: @JimB comment if there is any clue on this which would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: RE2 does not support lookarounds and will never support them.